# React- child to call parent function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following parent function that sets a function as its prop...

```
class Index extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {header:"Welcome to TutorHub"}

    }
    handleClick(event)
    {
     console.log("link was clicked");

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Inputs />   
            <Bottom event={this.handleClick()} /> 
        );
   }
}
export default Index;
```

Now I am calling this function in my child component onClick...

```
class Bottom extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {link:"Don't have an account?"}
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <div>
            <div className="sub-login">
                <p>{this.state.link}<a href="#" onClick={this.props.event}> Register here</a></p>
            </div>

            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Bottom;
```

So the function is being called, but it is not being called on `onClick`. Instead, the function is called as soon as the page loads. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your render, you are executing the method rather than passing a reference to it. Try the following instead:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Inputs />   
        <Bottom event={this.handleClick} /> 
    );
}
```

Comment: Ok I did that. Now the function is not called on load, but there is another problem, it is not being called onClick. Whenever I click the link there is not output on the console. Any reason why?